# Data Conversion using pyodbc to query iSeries database - Conversion error

Tags: python, sql, ibm-midrange, pyodbc, db2-400

I am trying to filter records based on a Zoned Decimal value that is returning as Decimal(160919, ).  How can I use this to filter against a date (ie: 160919)
Below is the code that I'm using to extract the order data:

```
#connect to APlus
import pyodbc
import time
import cursor as cursor


today = int(time.strftime("%y%m%d"))
whatisit = type(today)
print whatisit
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=aplus; uid=username;pwd=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = """ select OHORNO, OHRSDT
            from ORHED
            where OHCSNO = 206576  and CAST(OHRSDT AS INT) = '$[today]'"""
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchall()
if row :
    print(row)

print ("Today : " + today)
```

Comment: If for nothing other than posterity, please update the question to post the DDL for field OHRSDT of table ORHED, and the resolved value of the expression '$[today]'; e.g. by giving the string result for the assignment of variable named `query', as something like, and perhaps this is the effect: `… and CAST(OHRSDT AS INT) = '160919'`  Note: better to cast the literal selection value to match the column, than the other way [shown], but that is optional because the literal would be cast implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being a space at the end of the date in the record.  I used Left(OHEXDT, 6) to compare and everything is working as expected.

This actually only worked for an isolated occurrence, and then failed.

I am now using substring to pull out the numbers in the format I need to compare them to.

`where OHCSNO = 206576 and integer(substr(OHESDT,1,6)) = '160926'`

Thanks!

Comment: `The Date field is a zoned decimal field.` If it is, there should be no space at the end unless either a trailing space is somehow being added before the value is returned in the statement or it's a DDS sourced file and some program is putting bad data into the field. Either way, you should dig out the cause because there will likely be future similar problems at unpredictable times.

Comment: @user2338816 The data that I'm getting returned is: (Decimal('160919'), )  I am trying to extract '160919' to use as the value to compare on.  Is this something that you see as being possible?  Thanks!

Comment: That appears to be a DECIMAL (6,0) value in YYMMDD format. That is, there is no century digit given. It looks like 2016-09-19, or CURRENT DATE, in a possibly bad format.

Comment: @user2338816 I understand that, is there a way to extract the 6 digit portion of the value?  This is the standard format of the dates in our AS400 system.  Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Is this still related to the OP? It seems to be far enough away that it's not clear where any problem is now. Are you needing to return 6 characters from a "date" numeric value in the SELECT statement? Or are you trying to get python to convert a numeric value to 6 characters? Or...?

Comment: Please edit this answer to use the actual field name that was wrapped in the `LEFT` scalar, a field name from the Opening Post; i.e. there is no field named `field` in the OP, so the answer, as written, is quite confusing.

Comment: OP references OHRSDT, yet answer names OHEXDT and OHESDT. A trailing blank was not original issue, unless defect; i.e. cast to INT from string ignore trailing [& leading] blanks. **However** non-blanks or even a blank followed by a non-blank **would** cause a **Conversion error**; that **likely explains** the issue seen. Seems there is a need for definitional corrections and\or data *cleansing* of the stored so-called *date* strings. FWiW: the sqlcode was not noted in the OP; also a conversion error is likely logged as a data mapping error for which again, no note of that messaging at server.

Comment: @CRPence thank you!  I apologize for the lack of clarity in my OP, I'm new to doing this outside of IBM query.  All date fields referenced (OHRSDT, OHEXDT and OHESDT) are formatted alike but the data I needed to compare against evolved as my solution did.  Is there some way I can make my question better for future reference, or my answer for that matter?  Thanks!

Comment: To make the question a worthwhile resource for others, consider: Edit the OP and add DDL and sample data that re-creates the *Subject* issue, add the sqlcode [or whatever message] received and optionally add messaging from the server joblog, and update the query to be what actually failed with those errors, and include result of `print ("Today : " + today)` and\or `print ("Q: " + query)`. Then update the answer to reflect the actual redaction to the query [or just where-clause], from which resolution came. All optional, of course; but IMO, better than leaving a topic+answer so disjointed